# model binding in laravel like ASP NET Core

Tags: laravel, asp.net-core

I come from ASP NET Core and one of my favourite things was binding form inputs to a model properties. I saw on documentation for version 4.2 that it had something similar to MVC tag helpers when creating a form and inputs but that was removed from the newer versions. Was this feature replaced with a new one that I can't find or was basically just eliminated? It is really a painful task to just request the data per input on a large form one by one.

Comment: It's just that it's not shipped with laravel anymore. You can still use it. However, I personally think Blade components would be better to get familiarised with if you've just started using Laravel.

Comment: i suppose you are talking about the form builder that has form model binding, that is handled by the Laravel Collective now, `laravelcollective/html`

Comment: @lagbox is there any other way  to do something similar like this or do i need to install this dependency?

Comment: unless you like reinventing the wheel I would use what is already built and has been tested for years ;-)